# Exclude SQL query results - single table

Tags: sql

I am used to creating basic queries, so I am stuck on a rather complex one.

```
Order Number    Order Line    Package    Part Number    Size    Cost    Reviewed
   0001              1           1           A1          S      22.5      Yes
   0001              1           1           B2          M      33.1      Yes
   0001              1           1           C3          L      11.2      Yes
   0001              1           2           A1          XL     15.0      Yes
   0001              1           3           A2          M      12.0      Yes
   0001              2           1           D1          S      42.9      Yes
   0002              1           1           B4          L      72.5      No
   0002              1           2           A7         XXL     66.7      No
   0002              2           1           C1          XL     11.8      Yes
   0002              2           1           B1          S      22.3      Yes
   0003              1           1           A1          L      55.2      Yes
```

I would like to select Order Number, Order Line, and Package. I have to search by Part Number, Size, Cost, and if it was Reviewed. This table has around 30,000 orders, so there are multiple results (which is what I want). I got the easy part down, and it works correctly. Example:

```
SELECT
ORDER Number,
ORDER Line,
      Package
FROM TABLE
WHERE (Part Number='A1'
       AND SIZE='S'
       AND Cost='22.5'
       AND Reviewed='Yes')
GROUP BY ORDER Number,
         ORDER Line,
         Package 
HAVING count(ORDER Number)=1


Order Number    Order Line    Package
   0001              1           1
```

Here is my challenge. I have to exclude results that have an Order Line where Package <> 1. So the result for my example above will be excluded, because for Order Number 0001 - Order Line 1 contains a Package of 2 and 3. When this exclusion is applied, the only valid results in the table I provided should be...

```
Order Number    Order Line    Package
   0001              2           1
   0002              2           1
   0003              1           1
```

Do not worry about null values. Performance is a concern (obviously), as it is a large table. I have looked around, but I have not found any solid solutions for this yet. Your guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us what RDBMS and version are you using (Oracle 11g, SQL Server 2008, MySQL....)

Comment: @John K Why don't you just filter out those rows using a where condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will exclude records with a matching order_number and order_line that have a package other than 1:

```
SELECT
   ORDER_Number,
   ORDER_Line,
   Package
FROM 
   aTABLE
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM atable AS b
                    WHERE atable.order_number = b.order_number
                          AND atable.order_line = b.order_line
                          AND b.Package != 1)
GROUP BY ORDER_Number,
     ORDER_Line,
     Package
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Joe, but I do not get any results when I do this query. I think this might be missing something, but I will have to look into it further.

Comment: @JohnK The output of this is the same as the output from my question. What is incorrect in your result set when you use this logic? Here's the fiddle with Joe's version http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a350/28/0

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my query I created from your logic that passed the syntax, but gave me 0 results. I just checked it again. Your logic is correct, and very helpful. Thank you both @Joe and Jarek.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little hackish and not promising good performance, but I've used something like this before.

```
SELECT ORDERNumber,
       ORDERLine
FROM orders
GROUP BY ORDERNumber,
         ORDERLine 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN package = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)= 0
ORDER BY ordernumber,
         orderline
```

**[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a350/21/0)**

The case when part should be common across [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html), [SqlServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), and [Oracle](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php).

Comment: @meewoK He doesn't want an instance of an order line if it has a package <> 1. An order is split up into several rows, grouped by order line it seems, and each orderline can have multiple packages attached to it.

Comment: @meewoK Yeah that's usually the biggest challenge when writing queries like this, understanding the data, business rules, and figuring out exactly what the users question was.

Comment: Thanks @Jarek and meewK. Sorry for the confusion, it is difficult to explain the requirement. Jarek, your answer only has results with a 1 for my Order Line, which is correct. However, it still shows results for Order Lines that have a pacakge <> 1. I am trying to exclude those Order Lines. Please also note that this is being grouped by Order Number and Order Line.

Comment: @JohnK in the sqlFiddle I posted I get three rows back, 0001/2, 0002/2, and 0003/1 which is what I thought the expected result you were looking for. Is there something different between your actual data and the data I have in the fiddle?

Comment: @Jarek thanks for the response. Your query works correctly. However, I also need to select the Package along with Order Number and Order Line. When I select the Package with your query, it shows Order Lines that have a package <> 1. I am sure I can fix it if I look into it further, but I am going to go with Joe's suggestion. Using the Case When statement looks like it might slow down the performance more. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @JohnK Great thing about sql is that there's usually multiple ways to solve a single problem, Joe's solution does what you need so go with it. The reason adding package to my solution gives you results you don't want is because for the sum clause to work correctly it has to group all the packages of a single order line together. If you add package to the select and group by, each row is treated individually and not in context of the other packages in an orderline. My solution is just another way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a derived table if you use MYSQL.
Basically, this is efficient because it creates a temporary small derived table of all orderline(s) that have have packages <> 1. Then we join to the main query with NOT condition.

```
SELECT
d1.ORDERNumber,
d1.ORDERLine,
d1.Package
FROM data d1,    
(select distinct ORDERLINE, 
 PACKAGE from data 
 where NOT Package = 1)
as d2    
WHERE (PartNumber='A1'
       AND SIZE='S'
       AND Cost=22.5
       AND Reviewed='Yes' 
       AND NOT d1.orderline = d2.orderline)
GROUP BY ORDERNumber,
         ORDERLine,
         Package 
HAVING count(ORDERNumber)=1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b391e/8